# Is it a good idea to share source code between team?

Tags: team-management, quality-management

I have a strategy to split the development teams into feature team,
To make each team isolate and full-stack.
Each team may have 1-5 people and may switch after that feature is done.

This is a single big project, Having one frontend, Multiple microservices.
So each team may need to modify the code across those components.

I want to know if someone experiencing shared project source code between the team?

Is it a good idea to do this?

How is the code review process going to be?

How to control the quality and consistency without bottleneck?

Answer (score 1):

If you use Version Control software there should not be a problem sharing code.

You can easily see who changed what and when, and even why, if you insist they enter a comment when checking in.

This makes code review - especially of changes - trivial.

The version control software will also highlight conflicting changes to the same code, so that one fix doesn't overwrite another.

Examples of classic version control software include SVN subversion, GIT and many others.

Comment: Thank you for the answer :), We're using VC as usual. The question is how is the code review process going to be. Should we have a center person who also does the code? And if that's the case is it going to be the bottleneck? How to solve this :)

Comment: @b.ben There's no reason why only 1 person should be responsbile for handling code reviews. You _can_ do it like that, but you could also have the entire team pitch in, or rotate code review duty, or whatever works best for your teams. Maybe ask them.

Answer (score 1):

I think It depends on which kind of VCS do you use, the distributed one or the centralized VCS, and also on your organization's policies.

"The main difference between the two classes is that Centralized VCSs keep the history of changes on a central server from which everyone requests the latest version of the work and pushes the latest changes (no one has control over their pushes), and On the other hand, on a Distributed VCS, everyone has a local copy of the entire work’s history." [Link](https://www.oshyn.com/blog/2012/06/version-control-systems-distributed-vs-centralized)

Based on your company policies, you can assignee someone to have supervision on users' code in Distributed VCS format, before codes are pushed on the main server. It would be great to have an expert to control other developers' pushes, and also in this kind of VCS, you can allow developers to push directly when you don't have an access to your supervisor to omit the bottleneck.